# Saving Images onto an Image, and editing that Image

Tags: java, c#, visual-studio

Apologies for the tongue twister of a title, hopefully I can be clearer here!

I am doing a project in university, and I want to basically create a screen mock-up application.

I want to be able to drag components (buttons, labels, etc.) onto a screen and use them to picture what a website/application would look like.

I imagine that these components would be images themselves.

I'd like to know is it possible to create a screen mock-up with these components i have mentioned.

Ideally, you should be able to open a previously created 'screen' and move the components around and save the screen as the original.

Thanks a million in advance!

Comment: if you want to know *if it is possible*, Then **Yes**

Comment: Is there any tips on how to go about this?

Comment: 1) Chose which language you want to work with. By not doing this and by tagging for both Java and C# your question is already too broad by definition. 2) Learn how to create GUI's and how to draw in this language of choice. 3) Try to implement your mock up. 4) Come back with your more specific question and your code if stuck after completing these first steps.

Comment: I'm going to use C#. I know how to drag and drop in Visual Studio, but the aim of my project is to create an application where the user is to be able to design screen mock-ups themselves. They should also be able to close these mock-ups, and re-open them and move components around. The reason I don't have any specific questions is because I don't know which questions I should be asking. I'm not sure what type of file I would need to create in order to make these screen mock-ups (GUIs)

Comment: In other words, I want my user to be able to create screen mock up's themselves, so they can see what their website would look like. They also need to be able to make changes to these mock ups. If I saved these mock up's as images, then I wouldn't be able to re-open and edit them. So I'm not sure what file type these would be